# How to encrypt a string in IOS/Iphone using public key supplied from c#

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, rsa

I used both an RSA.h and RSA.m file.

http://code1.okbase.net/codefile/RSA.m_2013022220938_5.html

When encrypting using the public key in iOS, I am getting a result string. However, I am unable to decrypt the result in c# code.

```
NSData *cipher = [self encryptWithKey:[self getPublicKeyRef] plainData:plainData];
NSUInteger len = cipher.length;
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t *)[cipher bytes];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len * 3];
[result appendString:@"["];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (i) {
        [result appendString:@","];
    }
    [result appendFormat:@"%d", bytes[i]];
}
[result appendString:@"]"];
NSLog(@"VALL %@ %d",result,len);//Send as byte array string
```